# bash compare 2 word lists from file

Tags: bash

Hello I have 2 files with these words:

file: old.txt

```
toto
tata
tutu
```

file: new.txt

```
toto
tata
titi
tete
```

I would like to know the elements in more and less of these 2 lists.

in addition: titi, tete

less: tutu

Answer (score 2):

The [comm](http://www.unixcl.com/2009/08/linux-comm-command-brief-tutorial.html) command does that

```
~/Temp$ comm -23  <(sort old.txt) <(sort new.txt)
tutu

~/Temp$ comm -13  <(sort old.txt) <(sort new.txt)
tete
titi
```

You can also print both results:

```
~/Temp$ comm -3  <(sort old.txt) <(sort new.txt)
      tete
      titi
tutu
```

---

> Where option meaning is described in the **comm** man page :
>
> - -1 suppress lines unique to FILE1
> - -2 suppress lines unique to FILE2
> - -3 suppress lines that appear in both files

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -v -w -f old new
titi
tete
$ grep -v -w -f new old 
tutu
```

Comment: This method gets me false results comparing with the comm mehtod.

Comment: @ThibaudHulin You are not getting `titi, tete` and `tutu`? What are you getting instead?

Comment: Here is an example where it doens't get what I want : https://justpaste.it/8lcpk

Comment: @ThibaudHulin Oh, I didn't ignore partial matches in the original answer as there were none (grep switch `-w`, _Select  only  those  lines containing matches that form whole words._). Added the switch to above solution. Thanks for the heads up, sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff old.txt new.txt | sed -n 's/^</less:/p;s/^>/in addition:/p'
```

Use diff to show the differences and then use sed to reformat with "less:" and "in addition:"

Output:

```
less: tutu
in addition: titi
in addition: tete
```